# mongoose update only positive value and numbers

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to design a blockchain syncer, that sync every transaction into mongodb.
When i'm trying to modify account it give me minus value.

I have update the schema with min: 0 value but that doesn't work.

can anyone help me to get this fixed and get all positive values.

Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const addressSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    value: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0,
      min: 0
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
    },
}, { timestamps: true })
```

JS Code:

```
const outGoingValue = await getOutGoingRaw.vout[outGoingVout].value;
const outGoingAddress = await getOutGoingRaw.vout[outGoingVout].scriptPubKey.addresses[0];

                                    await Address
                                        .findOne({ address: outGoingAddress })
                                        .then(async val => {
                                            let newOut = parseFloat(val.value-outGoingValue).toFixed(8);
                                            await Address.updateOne({ _id: val._id }, { value: newOut }, {new: true})
                                        })
```

Value that come out is: -3e-8

Comment: `val.value-outGoingValue` - that is an error in JavaScript. There is another / correct way to refer fields with hyphen `-` as part of a field name.

Comment: @prasad_ val.value = the old value of database and outGoingValue is the value from the blockchain him self (this is never bigger then the value of database).

Comment: `-3e-8` is the exponential form of the number. You can get the decimal value as `(-3e-8).toFixed(10)`.

Comment: is there a way to remove the exponential form, so the mongodb save the decimals?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using mongoose, there exists a way to add some (custom) validator

here is an example

```js
value: {
type: Number,
      validate: {
        validator: function (v) {
          return v >= 0;
        },
        message: (props) => `${props.value} is not a positive number!`,
      },
      required: [true, 'User value required'],
}
```

change messages as you like